# Numbers.app - How do I add a series of columns

Tags: numbers, csv

I have a spreadsheet with about 600 rows and 20 columns.

I want to add a unique identifier to each cell so that I can use the exported CSV output in another app.

So I thought that I could add a column after each existing column, and then use a formula to populate the cells.

So, first, are there better ways to do this? and if not, is there a short cut to adding 20 new columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add a new column right after the existing column**:

1. Select one of the existing column.
2. Press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

Repeat for each existing column to create a new blank column on their right.

**To create 20 new column at once:**

1. Select 20 new column.
2. Press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Right Arrow</kbd>.

This one will create 20 blank column right after the existing column. You need to rearrange them later.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a shortcut to adding 20 new columns?

@ to [this list of Numbers shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14849)

> Add or remove rows and columns with content ............... Option-drag the resize button

The shortcut to add 20 new columns is to option-drag the resize button to 20 new columns.